# android execute HTTP request without AsyncTask?

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

my application getting multi Json information from server

aim looking for any way to execute `Http` request without `AsyncTask` , is there any way to do that or i have to keep using `AsyncTask` to get Json information from the server ?

Comment: Why not to use AsyncTask?

Comment: yes, you can use Thread ...

Comment: @Selvin no aim using AsyncTask but on same activity the application has 4 buttons for example when i click on button 1 and button 2 button 2 must wait button 1 tel its finished to executes the http i want to execute both 1 and 2 at same time

Comment: Why not just keep a simple boolean flag when an AsyncTask is running? You're forcing the user to not be able to interact in **any** way when you perform `HttpRequests` on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at the [Android Asynchronous Http Client (Loopj) library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). Here's an example of a "typical" http request.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: awesome but can i send cookies throw headers ?

Comment: its worked thank you very very very very much , but still i dont know dose it send cookies ? if so how ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cookies throw headers." The docs for cookies can be seen here - http://loopj.com/android-async-http/. You can add http headers with `client.addHeader("header name", "header value")`

Answer (score 0):

This is how u can do this

```
public class RequestClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    Context context;

    public RequestClient(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl){
    String responseString="";
    HttpClient client = null;
    try {
         client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
         HttpGet get = new HttpGet(LoginActivity.url);
         HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
         HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
         if (resEntityGet != null) {  
             responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
             Log.i("GET RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", "Error is "+e.toString());
    }
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
     return responseString.trim();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
         super.onPostExecute(response); 
        }
}
```

and u have to call it from the main class as

```
RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(this);
reqClient.execute().get();
```

Comment: this is what aim doing not , but aim looking for another wait to execute multi http at same time

Comment: have u tried this in a loop

Comment: RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(this);
reqClient.execute().get();
RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(this);
reqClient.execute().get();

Comment: se this link might help u somehow http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentthreading-part-2-async-tasks/